# Why is setting the innerHTML not working?

Tags: javascript, xml

My xml document is this:

```
<Order>
  <size width="16.5" height="19.5">
    <width>16.5</width>
    <height>19.5</height>
  </size>
  <type>photo</type>
  </overlay>
  <Mats></Mats>
  <Openings></Openings>
  <Moulding></Moulding>
  <Glass></Glass>
</Order>
```

I am trying to fill in the values of the Mats tag.
Here is my javascript code:

```
function common_get_order_xml()
{
  var parser = new DOMParser(); //create a new DOMParser
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(common_get_common_order_xml(), "application/xml"); //convert the string to xml
  console.log(doc); //outputs what is above
  //doc.getElementsByTagName('Mats').innerHTML = mattes_get_mattes_xml().replace("<Mats>", "").replace("</Mats>", ""); //add the mattes
  doc.getElementsByTagName('Mats').innerHTML = "TEST";
  doc.getElementsByTagName('Openings').innerHTML = mattes_get_openings_xml(); //Add the openings
  doc.getElementsByTagName('Moulding').innerHTML = moulding_get_moulding_xml(); //Add the moulding
  doc.getElementsByTagName('Glass').innerHTML = glazing_get_glass_xml(); //Add the moulding
  var serializer = new XMLSerializer(); //create a new XMLSerializer
  common_order_xml = serializer.serializeToString(doc); //convert the xml back to a string
  return doc;
}
```

But when I output doc, the Mats innerHTML does not get set to "TEST"

Comment: [*getElementsByTagName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) returns a [*NodeList*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), not a single element. Try `doc.getElementsByTagName('Mats')[0].innerHTML`.

Comment: @RobG is correct... also your XML is badly formed.  There is closing `</overlay>` without an opening tag.  Is it supposed to be a self-closing tag?  In which case use `<overlay/>`

Comment: @RobG that works. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

When using JavaScript with XML you shouldn't read and set the innerHTML, Chrome and Firefox try to allow you to do this but you can get some weird behavior.

Instead of accessing `something.innerHTML` try using `somthing.firstChild.data`.

Comment: Also what RobG said about the NodeList will need to be incorporated here as well.

Comment: — [*innerHTML*](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#innerhtml) should work in XML documents too, however browser support may not be as good as for HTML documents.